# Apply filter array/return terms

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to apply a filter on which taxonomies are displayed in a widget. I'm close but I think I don't have the correct spelling for it and I'm surely missing something :

```
add_filter( 'uael_posts_tax_filter', function( $terms ) {
   array('video-genres') // Modify the array here.
  return $terms;
}, 10, 2 );
```

What is missing?

Comment: thats a Wordpress specific function call. I added the wordpress tag

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? Please share more details

Comment: Yes I have a critical error if I set the code like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolve my issue. The code I was given and gave to you was just the beggining. Here the code in order to reach my goal :

```
add_filter( 'uael_posts_tax_filter', function( $terms ) {
$new_terms = array();
foreach ( $terms as $index => $tax ) {
    if( 'video-genres' === $tax->taxonomy ) { 
        $new_terms[] = $tax;
    }
}
return $new_terms; }, 10, 2 );
```

Thanks for your help and hope this could help someone in the futur.
Best regards,
Clément

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
add_filter('uael_posts_tax_filter', 'custom_uael_posts_tax_filter', 10, 2);
function custom_uael_posts_tax_filter($terms)
{
    // Modify the array here.
    if ($terms) {
        $terms[] = 'video-genres';
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Comment: I have a critical error when I use your form. It's ultimate addons for elementor and I'm inspiring from :https://ultimateelementor.com/docs/filters-actions-for-posts-widget/#helps-modify-the-terms-of-taxonomy-badge

Answer (score 0):

Where it says

> modify the array here

it means to modify the `$terms array` so it would contain only the terms you're aiming for.

And not just setting an array.

I'm not sure which plugin this is and how they have set their filters, but this one should work:

```
add_filter( 'uael_posts_tax_filter', function( $terms ) {

   $terms[] = 'video-genres';
  return $terms;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: I have a critical error when I use your form. It's ultimate addons for elementor and I'm inspiring from :https://ultimateelementor.com/docs/filters-actions-for-posts-widget/#helps-modify-the-terms-of-taxonomy-badge

Comment: it shouldn't pop a critical error. It might not related to my code. Can you debug the error and get more details?

Comment: Here what I see in debug when I activate your code : jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).isotope is not a function ....
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).isotope is not a function....
Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope 12 
​